# How to convert the Y axis values of scatter plot into percentage

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot Elbow curve for K Means clustering. I don't know how to  convert the Y axis into percentage (0-100). Any suggestions? Here is my code and output graph.

```
def eblow(df, n):
kMeansVar = [KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(df) for k in range(1, n)]
centroids = [X.cluster_centers_ for X in kMeansVar]
k_euclid = [cdist(df, cent) for cent in centroids]
dist = [np.min(ke, axis=1) for ke in k_euclid]
wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist]
tss = sum(pdist(df)**2)/df.shape[0]
bss = tss - wcss
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.xlabel("clusters")
plt.title("Variance explained vs K")
plt.ylabel("perecntage of variance (%)")
plt.plot(bss)
plt.show()
```

I have attached the resulting graph. I want to convert the Y axis into percentage but I am unable to do so.

[MY graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0VQB.png)

Comment: Is there any question? What exactly is the problem? Please read [ask]. Also, if this is about a problem in the code, provide a [mcve]  of the issue.

Comment: Percentage is a relative unit. So you want the quantity `bss` relative to what exactly? Once you know what that is (and you need to find that out for yourself, since it's not clear what you are doing in the code), you need to divide `bss` by it and multiply by 100 to get the percentage.